# Need help implementing coroutines, need to wait for the api response

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

My problem seems very simple but I somehow  can't get it working. I want to wait for the array to be filled after the api response.

**Starting the api request**

```
        val job = GlobalScope.launch(IO) {
            result = viewModel.getJsonFile()!!
        }
        runBlocking {
            job.join()
            Log.e("result", result.toString()) } }
        }
```

**next function**

```
suspend fun getJsonFile(): ArrayList<String>? {
        return RetrofitClient.createClient()
    }
```

**Retrofit Client**

```
suspend fun createClient(): ArrayList<String> {
        val url = "https://jobconcursosbr.com/"
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(APIrequests::class.java)
        GlobalScope.launch ( Dispatchers.IO ) {
            val response = api.getTextData()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                myTitles.clear()
                for (item in response.body()!!) {
                    myTitles.add(response.body()!![i].title.rendered)
                    Log.e("meusTitulos", myTitles[i])
                    minhaDescricao.add(response.body()!![i].content.rendered)
                    i++
            }
        }
    }
        return myTitles}
```

**Getting empty result**

```
2021-04-03 16:19:40.659 9484-9484/com.example.noticiasconcursos E/result: []
2021-04-03 16:19:43.435 9484-9546/com.example.noticiasconcursos E/meusTitulos: Processo Seletivo iNova Capixaba tem 877 vagas em vários níveis
2021-04-03 16:19:43.436 9484-9546/com.example.noticiasconcursos E/meusTitulos: ESPM disponibiliza cursos gratuitos online com certificado
2021-04-03 16:19:43.436 9484-9546/com.example.noticiasconcursos E/meusTitulos: IFPR disponibiliza cursos gratuitos de inglês básico e intermediário online
2021-04-03 16:19:43.436 9484-9546/com.example.noticiasconcursos E/meusTitulos: Senar oferece 40 cursos gratuitos de capacitação na região norte de SC
```

How can I use corroutines properly? I want the Log to show after the array is filled with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the coroutine scope from your createClient function

```
 suspend fun createClient(): ArrayList<String> {
        val url = "https://jobconcursosbr.com/"
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(APIrequests::class.java)
            val response = api.getTextData()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                myTitles.clear()
                for (item in response.body()!!) {
                    myTitles.add(response.body()!![i].title.rendered)
                    Log.e("meusTitulos", myTitles[i])
                    minhaDescricao.add(response.body()!![i].content.rendered)
                    i++
            }
    }
        return myTitles}
```

Comment: Removed "suspend" from createClient() but nothing changed.... Still getting the same results :(

Comment: no don't remove the suspend from createClient remove GlobalScope.launch ( Dispatchers.IO ) inside it because in your code the part api.getTextData() is run on different coroutine because of it

Comment: It worked, However I think I am freezing for some seconds my UI by doing this...

Comment: replace this val job = GlobalScope.launch(IO) with CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).lanuch

Answer (score 1):

You can observe using myTitles(live data)
myTitle.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
......
})

Comment: I will be doing this, seems like the correct way.